# UI Automator shows error upon capturing one of a screen of an App under test

Tags: android, ui-automation, appium-android, uiautomatorviewer

I have the appium stopped and all ports are free but still upon capturing a screen's screenshot using UI AUTOMATOR an error comes over

Unable to capture a screenshot of one of the screen that appears after logging into the App. After loggin in, the screen shows list of members. You can think of a list just as we have in our contact list.

no code required since it's just an issue with UI AUTOMATOR

[image: ErrorUponCapturingScreen_UIautomator]

Comment: and how about the `Details >>` ??

Comment: Martin Zeitler  it's totally the same as mentioned below Reason: heading.

Comment: try running `adb exec-out uiautomator dump /dev/tty` in the terminal window, because the error message displayed in the GUI is not really helpful / too understandable.

Comment: it comes up with this:
C:\Users\waqas.ahmed>adb exec-out uiautomator dump /dev/tty
ERROR: could not get idle state.

Comment: I used below commands but still not working:
(1) adb shell am force-stop com.android.ddmlib  (2) adb exec-out uiautomator dump /dev/tty
both are coming up with same error: "ERROR: could not get idle state."

Comment: `/dev/tty` is useless on Windows, but I think I've found a plausible answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Github](https://github.com/appium/appium-uiautomator2-server/pull/80), the idle-timeout can be adjusted with:

```
driver.setSetting(Setting.WAIT_FOR_IDLE_TIMEOUT, 0);
```

Maybe try a value alike `2000` or `5000` milliseconds there,

because it likely only can dump it, when the UI is in idle state.

Comment: do I need to write this line in a method where I am locating all elements? or in which Settings should I add it to avoid this issue?

Comment: I mean how this line is going to resolve this issue when the Appium is also off and I am just playing with UI Automator :O

Comment: It's the [appium-android-driver](https://github.com/appium/appium-android-driver). One could also build a custom `UiAutomator2` (as another issue there suggested), but setting it through the Android driver should do the job.

Comment: Can this be the cause of throwing this error that the screen I'm trying to capture has a floating camera icon too?
 Though, loads of thanks for the guide Martin Zaeitlet. I'm just trying to get into things so instead of getting stuck at UI tool, an alternate tool (Appium Desktop)is working for me. leaving this issue as is...